# Bootstrap style in form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, form-for

Since the dropdown list is generated dynamically, how would i use bootstrap dropdown style on dropdown `f.select` in `form_for`.

```
= form_for (@blog), html: {class: "form-horizontal", role: "form"} do |f|
    .col-sm-6.well
        .form-group
            label.control-label.col-sm-2 for= 'name'
                |User
            .col-sm-8
                = f.select :user_id, User.all.collect {|p| [ p.full_name, p.id ] }
```

Currently it looks like :

[image: not bootstrap]

Answer (score -1):

Add `{ class: "selectpicker" }`

Where "selectpicker" is the name of the class

```
= f.select :user_id, User.all.collect {|p| [ p.full_name, p.id ] },
               { class: "selectpicker" }
```